# Can't connect to Azure DocumentDB using MongoDB Compass or MongoVUE

Tags: azure, mongodb

I've created a DocumentDB instance on Microsoft Azure, but I'm unable to connect to it from MongoDB Compass (or MongoVUE).  In MongoDB Compass, I've entered all of the connection parameters and it is logging in, however then it opens a windows which just sits there with a loading icon forever.  I can connect to a MongoDB instance on the local machine, so I know that works.  Is MongoDB Compass incompatible with DocumentDB for some reason?  Is there another tool that I can use to connect and browse my DocumentDB instance?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br6rP.png)

Comment: Have you enabled MongoDB support for DocumentDB (as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-connect-mongodb-account)? DocumentDB implements a subset of the MongoDB query language so I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work fully with tools expecting a MongoDB server. There is a tutorial for MongoChef, so that seems a more supported option to try: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef.

Answer (score 0):

MongoVUE uses an outdated version of MongoDb drivers,and I'm guessing it doesn't support ssl. I also cannot connect using MongoVUE. I also cannot use MongoDB Compass.
With Robomongo and MongoBooster I can connect.

Be sure to en able SSL with self signed Certificate.

[image: see screenshot]